# angular2 - cannot get data from web service

Tags: web-services, angular, angular2-observables

Learning typescript & angular2 for the first time. I'm creating a generic service that just does GET and POST so that I can use it in the entire app. I've based my app on Angular's example from [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-dynamic-form/ts/eplnkr.html)

My issue is that my "QuestionService" is using a "ServerService" but it is complaining that `this.ServerService.getData is not a function` isnt a function.

**ServerService**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ServerService {

    private apiUrl = 'app/users.json';

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getData (): Observable<any>[] {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

**QuestionService**

```
import { ServerService } from './server.service';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionService implements OnInit{

    errorMessage: string;
    mode = 'Observable';
    questions: QuestionBase<any>[];
    ServerService = ServerService;

    ngOnInit() { this.getQuestions(); }

    getQuestions(ServerService: ServerService<any>){
        console.log('getQuestions');
        console.log(this.ServerService.getData());

        this.ServerService.getData()
                    .subscribe(
                      questions => this.questions = questions,
                      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
```

Here is the url: https://plnkr.co/edit/InWESfa6PPVKE0rXcSFG?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is let Angular *inject* the `ServerService` into the `QuestionService`, just like are doing with the `Http` inside the `ServerService`

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionService implements OnInit{

    constructor(private serverService: ServerService) {}

    ngOnInit() { this.getQuestions(); }

    getQuestions(){
        this.serverService.getData()
                    .subscribe(
                      questions => this.questions = questions,
                      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

Then you need to add both services to the `providers` array

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [ServerService, QuestionService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```