# observables are not assigning variables

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm trying to inject a DataService in QuestionService but when I assign 'this.questions2', the AppComponent still thinks the value is undefined. I get

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:3:20 caused by: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/InWESfa6PPVKE0rXcSFG?p=preview)

**QuestionService**

```
getQuestions(DataService: DataService<any>){
    this.DataService.getData()
        .subscribe(
            function(response) { 
                this.questions2 = response;
                return this.questions2;                   
            },

            function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
            function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
        );
    }
```

**DataService**

```
getData (){
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body || { };
  }
```

**appcomponent**

```
import { QuestionService } from './question.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Job Application for Heroes</h2>
      <dynamic-form [questions]="questions"></dynamic-form>
    </div>
  `,
  providers:  [QuestionService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  questions: any[];

  constructor(service: QuestionService) {
//why is the line below undefined?!
    this.questions = service.getQuestions();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using observables correctly. Then end user is the one that should subscribe. When you do this in your questions service

```
getQuestions(DataService: DataService<any>){
    this.DataService.getData()
        .subscribe(
            function(response) { 
                this.questions2 = response;
                return this.questions2;                   
            },

            function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
            function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
        );
}
```

The return in the function doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't mean that you can do

```
questions = service.getQuestions();
```

That's not how it works. It's the component that should subscribe to the service observable. So really, if you take that into consideration, the question service is useless. It has not purpose. The data service is doing all the work. So if you still wanted to use the questions service, then you would simply return the call to `getData`

```
getQuestions() {
  return this.dataService.getData();
}
```

Like I said, it's pretty useless. Then in your component, is where you subscribe to the service

```
getQuestions().subscribe((data) => {
  this.questions = data;
})
```

**Other things to mention:**

- You need to learn to make use of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for callbacks, instead of the `function` keyword.
- It looks like you are still making the same mistake with the `DataService` is in your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41092825/2587435).
- In your component, you should initialize the `questions` to an empty array. `questions = []`, because the observable subscription is asynchronous and if it is not initialized, the template will try to use the undefined value.

Comment: thanks for the response. I want to be able to use the DataService to fetch other json objects (in the future) not just 'users.json'. I've only hard coded it for now just to get something started. I've created this https://plnkr.co/edit/InWESfa6PPVKE0rXcSFG?p=preview with your changes. But I am now getting a different error. Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

Comment: Please review your previous questions. Looks like a problem that you have already faced and should have learned from. As I also mentioned in my answer